# flot chart with json data is empty

Tags: php, jquery, json, charts, flot

I need to plot chart in flot with data returned by a php script as json encoded data
i get the data in through jquery like this

```
$("button").click(function(){
    var dp1 = $('#dp1').val();
    var dp2 = $('#dp2').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "chart.php",
        datatype:"json",
        success: onSuccess,
        data: {d1:dp1, d2:dp1}
        });

    function onSuccess(series) {

        var plotarea = $("#pieChart");  
        plotarea.css("height", "300px");  
        plotarea.css("width", "400px");  
        $.plot( plotarea , [
        {
            data: series,
            bars: {
                show: true
            }
        }
        ] );  
    }
});
```

the data return is json encoded i can see it in firebug like so

```
[["ebbok1",39.55],["ebbok2",92.23],["ebbok3",102.44]]
```

but my chart is empty

[image: empty_flot_chart]

the php file returning the json data is

```
$dataset = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
  //echo $row['amount'] . "\t" . $row['product_name']. "\n";
  $dataset[] = array( $row['product_name'], $row['amount'] );
}
echo json_encode($dataset,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

what am i doing wrong?

**EDIT**

i modified my php script, it now returns data like this

`[{"label":"ebook1","data":39.55},{"label":"ebook2","data":92.23},{"label":"ebook3","data":102.44}]`

but i still get empty chart

Comment: What does your echo retrun? echo json_encode($dataset,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

Comment: echo returns json encoded string in the result tab in firedebug, it shows up like this `[["ebbok1",39.55],["ebbok2",92.23],["ebbok3",102.44]]`

Comment: Ah yes sorry, missed that part. My josn comes back with {} braces not [].  Try returning {"result":[{0:"ebbok1",39.55}],[{1:"ebbok2",92.23}]}

Comment: i was able to return `"result":[{"1":["ebbok1",39.55]},{"2":["ebbok2",92.23]},{"3":["ebbok3",102.44]}]}`, but still got empty chart

Comment: That might not be the solution as flot requires a dataset which is what it looks like is being returned. I am still looking.

Comment: Have you tried hardcoding some data into the $.plot instead of passing series? If it doesn't work then it's not your data.

Comment: Check these out. http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/ajax.html

Comment: yes when i hardcode data like these `[{"1":["ebbok1",12]},{"2":["ebook1",27.55]},{"3":["ebook2",92.23]},{"4":["ebook3",102.44]}]` or like this `[{"ebbok1":[1,12]},{"ebook1":[2,27.55]},{"ebook2":[3,92.23]},{"ebook3":[4,102.44]}]` i still get and empty chart. Wne i use this `[[1,12],[2,27.55],[3,92.23],[4,102.44]]` however i get a chart whith bars, but numbers on both sides, i want the name of the books on one axis and the figures on the other axis

Comment: You need to pass label into it for the label and data for the data. Try $dataset[] = array('label'=>$row['product_name'], 'data'=>$row['amount'] );

Comment: yes, i already did that, this is the output `[{"label":"ebbok1","data":12},{"label":"ebook1","data":27.55},{"label":"ebook2","data":92.23},{"label":"ebook3","data":102.44}]` but still empty chart

Comment: Should be working. Try one of the tutorial examples and then modify it for your use. That's all I can suggest dude.

Comment: Any javascript errors?

Comment: no, no javascript error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$.plot` call doesn't look correct.  You are mixing the options and data together.

```
var series = [
    {"label":"ebbok1","data":12},
    {"label":"ebook1","data":27.55},
    {"label":"ebook2","data":92.33},
    {"label":"ebook3","data":102.44}
];

$.plot( $("#somePlot") , series,
  {
    series: {
        pie: {
            show: true
        }
    }
  }
);
```

See fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8gGEz/).

Comment: Thanks for making the example, Mark... I think they wanted bars though?  I was already answering when you posted, so I just finished it off in mine...

Answer (score 2):

You've misunderstood how a set of data is expected for flot.

You have:

```
series = [["label",1],["label2",2],... ];
```

Flot expects data formatted like this:

```
series = [[[x1,y1],[x2,y2],...]];// where xN and yN are all NUMBERS
```

See also the [documentation](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#data-format) on this topic.

So assuming that you really want to see the labels you've specified, one way to deal with that is to use the `ticks` property of the xaxis.  So you'd return two sets of data:

```
data = [[[0,1],[1,1],...]];
tickLabels = [[0,"label1"],[1,"label2"],...];
```

Then in your flot options specify this:

```
   $.plot( plotarea , data, {
      series: {
         bars: {
            show:true;
         }
      },
      xaxis: {
         ticks:tickLabels
      }
   } );
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/8gGEz/1/

**EDIT**: If you want to keep returning your series data the same way, you can do the manipulation in the javascript:

```
var tickLabels = [];
for (var i =0;i<series.length;i++){
    tickLabels.push([i,series[i][0]);
    series[i][0] = i;
}
var data = [series];

//now you can call flot as I described above.
```

Comment: am fetching my data dynamically through ajax, how do i get the ticks and data from php the way you formatted?

Comment: my data is now currently returned as `[{"label":"ebook1","data":39.55},{"label":"ebook2","data":92.23},{"label":"ebook3","data":102.44}]` but i still get an empty chart but with labels. when i try in jsfiddle, i get a chart but in my website, its empty only labels show up. The point here is that my data are not all numbers, but a label and a number

Comment: ah, my example will only work if your data is returned as arrays that look like `[["ebook1",39.55],["ebook2",92.23],...]`

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same problem with you. But now I figure it out.
The problem is cause by your data

```
[["ebbok1",39.55],["ebbok2",92.23],["ebbok3",102.44]]
```

It look like what you want to show at x-axis is "category" type. 
So [flot(v0.8.2)](http://www.flotcharts.org/) provide '[categories](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/categories/)' mode to present the x-axis show what you want as categories.
As following:

Step1: add categories module to your HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="flot/jquery.flot.categories.js"></script>
```

Step2: add the following to your js.

```
   var options={ 
      xaxis:{mode: "categories"}
   };
```

try it and enjoy it :)